# Exchanging Authorization Code for Access Token for Google Calendar API with VBA and Oauth2

Tags: vba, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

After successfully obtaining the authorization code, I am having trouble exchanging it for an access token and refresh token while trying to access the Google Calendar API. I get Error 404 Not Found. Here is my code:

```
Dim getTokenUrl As String
getTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/auth2/token"

Dim getTokenBody As String
getTokenBody = "code=" & code & _
        "&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" & _
        "&client_id=xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" & _
        "&client_secret={myLittleSecret}" & _
        "&grant_type=authorization_code"

Dim Http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60                 
Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")  

With Http
    .Open "POST", getTokenUrl, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send(getTokenBody)
End With
Do While Http.ReadyState <> 4
Loop

Debug.Print Http.responseText
```

I have also tried putting everything in the url parameter of the .Open method and nothing in the .Send method:

```
Dim getTokenUrl As String
getTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token&code=" & code & "&client_id=xxxxxx-xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={myLittleSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code"

Dim Http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60                 
Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")  

With Http
    .Open "POST", getTokenUrl, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send("")
End With
```

I have tried using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest instead of MSXML2.XMLHTTP.

I have tried using `http://localhost` instead of urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob.

I have tried making `http://localhost` and urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob url encoded.

All give Error 404 Not Found.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hey @autoKarma could you please post the VBA code you used to obtain the authorization code? I can't find clear instructions on how to do this anywhere... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out--

The URL I was using was wrong--a one-letter type-o /forehead-slap/

instead of:

```
Dim getTokenUrl As String
getTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/auth2/token"
```

it should have been:

```
Dim getTokenUrl As String
getTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
```

note the `oauth2` instead of just `auth2`

Geesh. Sometimes I just need more sleep.

Incidentally, I could only get it to work when I put only the base URL in the .Open request and the parameters in the .send() (rather than stringing them all together in to one URL and "POST"ing it).

Working like a charm now!